# I'm Having Page Listing Issue in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, menu-list

I'm working on a menu listing. And I succeeded. But I'm having trouble with the submenu. The first submenu appears, but the others don't.

Do you have any idea what the model and controller codes are down there?

Models :

```
public function menuSira($list, $parent = 0)
{
    echo '<ul class="sub-menu">';
    foreach ($list as $sirala) {
        if ($sirala['ustmenu'] == $parent) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'. $sirala['link'] .'">';
            echo $sirala['menu']; 
            echo '</a>';
            echo $this->menuSira($list, $sirala['id']);
            echo '</li>'; 
        }
    } 
    echo '</ul>';       
}
```

Controller :

```
public function ustmenu()
{
    $data = [
        'ust' => $this->model->orderBy('sira', 'asc')->menuSira( $this->model->findAll())
    ];

    return view('tema/tema_part/tema_anasayfa/tema_header/tema_navbar', $data);
}
```

Comment: while saying "others" you mean the second level sub menus or rest of the submenus having parent id 0?

Comment: Yes. I'm having trouble sorting submenus. The first of the submenordination appears, the others do not. kontakdemo.zirkonteknoloji.com it's right here.

Comment: second and other menu items do not appear because of the CSS paddings. If you check the page source, you'll see they're there. About sorting can't say anything without seeing your `orderBy` method.

Comment: I shared the orderby method above in the controller. But I don't think it has anything to do with him. It could be css den, as you said.

Comment: merge two query togather with php then send it to layout

Comment: How can I do it?